# Write (also compile and execute) a complete C-program that implement a 5-band resistor color code

Tags: c

I have tried writing this code and have been getting errors and I still do not know what to do. I need help in writing the fixing the errors I get in lines 27-28. I also need help in writing the calculation end of the code. I am using the visual studio 2019 software in writing C language programs and I am very confused on how to finish this task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define DATA 128
#define RESISTOR_COLORS 11

int checkColorEntry(char[20]);
char* colorSeqEntry();

int main() {
    char sequenceColor1[20], sequenceColor2[20], sequenceColor3[20],sequenceColor4[20], sequenceColor5[20];



        sscanf(colorSeqEntry(), "%s %s %s %s %s", &sequenceColor1, &sequenceColor2, &sequenceColor3, &sequenceColor4, &sequenceColor5);
    while (checkColorEntry(sequenceColor1) != 0 || checkColorEntry(sequenceColor2) != 0 || checkColorEntry(sequenceColor3) != 0  ||
            checkColorEntry(sequenceColor4) != 0 || checkColorEntry(sequenceColor5) != 0 ){
        sscanf(colorSeqEntry(), "%s %s %s %s %s", &sequenceColor1, &sequenceColor2, &sequenceColor3, &sequenceColor4, &sequenceColor5);
    }
}

char* colorSeqEntry(){
    char *colorSequence = malloc(DATA);
    printf("\n\nPlease Input A Five Color Sequence, Separated By A Space: ");
    fgets(colorSequence, 254, stdin);
    return strupr(colorSequence);
}

int checkColorEntry(char seqColor[20]){
    char *resistorColors[RESISTOR_COLORS] = { "BLACK",
                                              "BROWN",
                                              "RED",
                                              "ORANGE",
                                              "YELLOW",
                                              "GREEN",
                                              "BLUE",
                                              "VIOLET",
                                              "GREY",
                                              "WHITE",
                                              "GOLD",
                                              "SILVER"};
    int i = 0, errors = 0, flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < RESISTOR_COLORS ; ++i) {

    if(strcmp(resistorColors[i], seqColor) == 0) {
        printf("Gotcha! %s %s\n", seqColor, resistorColors[i]);
        flag = 1;
    }
    }

    if (flag != 1){
        printf("\n%s -- Is Not A Color For A 5 Band Resistor", seqColor);
        flag = 0;
        errors++;
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: i did test your code with CodeBlocks and compiled and run, please write what exactly is error

Comment: Have you tried searching this site with `"[c] calculating resistor value"`? There are likely already examples to review.

Answer (score 0):

in line `strupr` maybe is unknown because it's not a standard function

so you can replace it with following function

```
char* to_upper(char* str) {
    char* pStr = str;
    while (*pStr != '\0') {
        if (*pStr >= 'a' && *pStr <= 'z') {
            *pStr = *pStr - 32;
        }
        pStr++;
    }
    return str;
}
```

another warning is `RESISTOR_COLORS` that must be 12

for calculation you can use following function

```
int color_index(char* color) {
    int i;
    char *resistorColors[RESISTOR_COLORS] = { "BLACK",
                                              "BROWN",
                                              "RED",
                                              "ORANGE",
                                              "YELLOW",
                                              "GREEN",
                                              "BLUE",
                                              "VIOLET",
                                              "GREY",
                                              "WHITE",
                                              "GOLD",
                                              "SILVER"};

    for (i = 0; i < RESISTOR_COLORS ; i++) {
        if(strcmp(resistorColors[i], color) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
long pow10(long p) {
    long x = 1;
    while (p-- > 0) {
        x *= 10;
    }
    return x;
}
// no telorance
long calculate_5band(char* c1, char* c2, char* c3, char* c4) {
    long digit1 = color_index(c1);
    long digit2 = color_index(c2);
    long digit3 = color_index(c3);
    long digit4 = color_index(c4);

    if (digit1 != -1 && digit2 != -1 && digit3 != -1 && digit4 != -1) {
        return ((digit1 * 100) + (digit2 * 10) + digit3) * pow10(digit4);
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define DATA 128
#define RESISTOR_COLORS 12

int checkColorEntry(char[20]);
char* colorSeqEntry();
char* to_upper(char* str);

long calculate_5band(char* c1, char* c2, char* c3, char* c4);

int main() {

    char sequenceColor1[20], sequenceColor2[20], sequenceColor3[20],sequenceColor4[20], sequenceColor5[20];



    sscanf(colorSeqEntry(), "%s %s %s %s %s", &sequenceColor1, &sequenceColor2, &sequenceColor3, &sequenceColor4, &sequenceColor5);
    printf("Resistor Value: %ld\n", calculate_5band(sequenceColor1, sequenceColor2, sequenceColor3, sequenceColor4));
    while (checkColorEntry(sequenceColor1) != 0 || checkColorEntry(sequenceColor2) != 0 || checkColorEntry(sequenceColor3) != 0  ||
            checkColorEntry(sequenceColor4) != 0 || checkColorEntry(sequenceColor5) != 0 ){
        sscanf(colorSeqEntry(), "%s %s %s %s %s", &sequenceColor1, &sequenceColor2, &sequenceColor3, &sequenceColor4, &sequenceColor5);
        printf("Resistor Value: %ld\n", calculate_5band(sequenceColor1, sequenceColor2, sequenceColor3, sequenceColor4));
    }
}

char* colorSeqEntry(){
    char *colorSequence = malloc(DATA);
    printf("\n\nPlease Input A Five Color Sequence, Separated By A Space: ");
    fgets(colorSequence, 254, stdin);
    return to_upper(colorSequence);
}

int checkColorEntry(char seqColor[20]){
    char *resistorColors[RESISTOR_COLORS] = { "BLACK",
                                              "BROWN",
                                              "RED",
                                              "ORANGE",
                                              "YELLOW",
                                              "GREEN",
                                              "BLUE",
                                              "VIOLET",
                                              "GREY",
                                              "WHITE",
                                              "GOLD",
                                              "SILVER"};
    int i = 0, errors = 0, flag = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < RESISTOR_COLORS ; ++i) {

    if(strcmp(resistorColors[i], seqColor) == 0) {
        printf("Gotcha! %s %s\n", seqColor, resistorColors[i]);
        flag = 1;
    }
    }

    if (flag != 1){
        printf("\n%s -- Is Not A Color For A 5 Band Resistor", seqColor);
        flag = 0;
        errors++;
    }
    return errors;
}

char* to_upper(char* str) {
    char* pStr = str;
    while (*pStr != '\0') {
        if (*pStr >= 'a' && *pStr <= 'z') {
            *pStr = *pStr - 32;
        }
        pStr++;
    }
    return str;
}

int color_index(char* color) {
    int i;
    char *resistorColors[RESISTOR_COLORS] = { "BLACK",
                                              "BROWN",
                                              "RED",
                                              "ORANGE",
                                              "YELLOW",
                                              "GREEN",
                                              "BLUE",
                                              "VIOLET",
                                              "GREY",
                                              "WHITE",
                                              "GOLD",
                                              "SILVER"};

    for (i = 0; i < RESISTOR_COLORS ; i++) {
        if(strcmp(resistorColors[i], color) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
long pow10(long p) {
    long x = 1;
    while (p-- > 0) {
        x *= 10;
    }
    return x;
}
// no telorance
long calculate_5band(char* c1, char* c2, char* c3, char* c4) {
    long digit1 = color_index(c1);
    long digit2 = color_index(c2);
    long digit3 = color_index(c3);
    long digit4 = color_index(c4);

    if (digit1 != -1 && digit2 != -1 && digit3 != -1 && digit4 != -1) {
        return ((digit1 * 100) + (digit2 * 10) + digit3) * pow10(digit4);
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

for verification you can use this [site](https://www.calculator.net/resistor-calculator.html)